# Can't fix errors while updating

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

I keep getting these errors when I run `sudo apt-get update` and I have also removed mongodb and Unifi from my system as well. These are the errors I get. I do not want these on my system anymore either. I do not have a need for them

````
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG BC711F9BA15703C6 MongoDB 3.4 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
Hit:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wireshark-dev/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Reading package lists... Done 
E: Repository 'http://dl.ubnt.com/unifi/debian stable InRelease' changed its 'Codename' value from 'unifi-5.10' to 'unifi-5.12'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG BC711F9BA15703C6 MongoDB 3.4 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>```
````

Comment: Questions should be more specific to the technology and problems!